# Have data being returned in an attribute

Tags: xml, attributes, xquery

```
for $Citypop in  doc("mondial.xml")//city[population > 1000000]/population[last()]
let $Cityname := doc("mondial.xml")//city[population = $Citypop]/name
let $Countryname := doc("mondial.xml")/$Cityname/../../name/../../name
let $Countrypop := doc("mondial.xml")/$Countryname/../population
let $popshare := 100*($Citypop[1] div $Countrypop[1])
return <city> {$Cityname} </city>
```

This will return a lot of different city names as follows from the `$Cityname` variable above. What I can't seem to do is return `$popshare` or `$Countryname` variables as attributes. So I would want the format to look like:

```
<city popshare="20" country="Spain">Madrid</city>
```

All I get now is:

```
<city>Madrid</city>
```

I've tried something like:

```
<city country= $Countryname >
```

but the syntax won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should brush up on XML and XQuery fundamentals. In XML, all attributes must be in quotes, and to evaluate an expression in an attribute value in XQuery you need curly braces (otherwise it will output the literal value in quotes).

```
<city country="{ $Countryname }" />
```

In XSLT this is called the Attribute Value Template. I don't think XQuery calls it the same thing, but the concept is basically identical:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-attributes

Comment: Ahaa ok i've just started Xquery a couple of days ago. Been stuck on this problem for a frustratingly long time today. I will brush up on XQuery though. Thanks alot !

Comment: @Super_Soet If this answer works for you, please accept it by clicking the little checkbox to the left.